# Good way to implement what "Virtual Static" could have? With simple example case

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static, polymorphism, virtual

First of all, let me be clear, this is NOT another question of why virtual static doesn't work, so please restrain yourself from answering how the compiler sees virtual and static or flag this as duplicate of those questions, but if you know any questions with answers fitting my example then feel free to link and flag duplicate.

Now by searching around for how to implement something that would have been solved this way, there're many people saying "I don't even know why you would need to do that" and the few examples of people trying to ask the same questions as me have very different examples so I find it hard to relate other people's answers.

So, in this game I wanna make I'm gonna have a simple `Inventory` and `Item` system. Every `Item` inherits from a `virtual class` that the `Inventory` class can recognize

```
public class Item {
    public virtual static Sprite getIcon();
    public virtual static string getName();
}

public class Stone : Item {
    static Sprite icon;
    static string name = "Stone";

    public override static Sprite getIcon(){
        return icon;
    }
    public override static string getName(){
        return icon;
    }

    // ...
}
```

So the thought basically is that every `Stone` shares the same `icon` in your `Inventory` and that all stones have the same name/title, say for using in debug messages or giving the player some message of what he's looking at or picking up.

Now all my guts tell me that best practice is that the `Sprite` should be `static`, since all instances of `Stone` in the `Inventory` should show the same `icon`. However, all kinds of items should also have a `Sprite`, thus they should `inherit` a common `get`-method to retrieve these.

So the two alternatives I came up with feels conventionally wrong or overkillishly wrong.

1) Make the `get`-methods non-`static` and make them return the content of the static members. This is unconventional as it makes overhead for every instance of a class where the return value is the same for every instance.

**EDIT:** Correction, there's no extra overhead and thus this method is the way to go.

2) Make some master class that stores all the sprites/names and returns them based of the type of the given object. First of all I don't like using type comparing/checking as I am of the impression that it's best to avoid doing so if you can. But even so I feel like this solution is overkill for such trivial tasks as to return a `string` or a `Sprite` reference

So unless I'm missing something, is there no straight-forward way of achieving this? Or are one of my two methods better than I think they are?

PS: I'm gonna implement this for a Unity game, so if unity provides a solution I'm all ears.

Comment: *This is unconventional as it makes overhead for every instance of a class where the return value is the same for every instance.* Virtual methods have no per-instance overhead.

Comment: @PetSerAl I might have used the wrong term. But are you saying that there's no memory/performance downside at all to not use a static method for that kind of methods?

Comment: @Chexxor correct, there is no penalty for it, just make a normal virtual method that references a private static field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When in Rome, do as the Romans do. :)

If you use C# then I suggest avoiding Java-style coding.

For example method names are in `PascalCase` form instead of `camelCase` form and C# also has `properties` instead of getter/setter methods. So here is my suggestion:

```cs
public abstract class Item
{
    public abstract Sprite Icon { get; }

    public abstract string Name { get; }
}

public class Stone : Item
{
    private static readonly Sprite icon = Sprite.Create(/* parameters omitted */);

    private const string name = "Stone";

    // expression-bodied member: supported as of C# 6
    public override Sprite Icon => icon;

    // traditional propery getter
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

What you can see here:

- You can override properties and methods that are marked with `abstract` or `virtual` or `override` keywords. I made `Item` class and its properties as `abstract`, hence I do not need to implement the properties in the `Item` class, and only derived types like `Stone` can be instantiated which must override the properties.
- As the `icon` field's value will not change I applied `readonly` keyword as well so that it cannot be changed.
- The `name` field could be also `readonly` but instead of `static readonly string` fields we use `const` keyword which makes `name` field not only `static` but also its value cannot be changed. **Please note:** `static readonly` and `const` behave differently, see [here](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/const-vs-static-vs-readonly-in-c-sharp-applications/).
- The overridden properties are in 2 forms: the `Name` property is implemented in the traditional C# way, the `Icon` property is implemented with the new [`expression-bodied member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) feature.

To sum it up, no offense, my intention was only to show how your solution can be implemented in a more C#-way that does not look like Java.

Comment: This answer proves very useful! I didn't know coming from Java would be that obvious ;) Anyways, these coding tips was more than I asked for, but exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With some clarification from commenters I found that the first solution I stated is actually the straight-forward answer I was looking for. Simply make the variables static, but the inherited/overriden method non-static, but use it to retrieve the static values.

```
public class Item {
    public virtual Sprite getIcon();
    public virtual string getName();
}

public class Stone : Item {
    static Sprite icon;
    static string name = "Stone";

    public override Sprite getIcon(){
        return icon;
    }
    public override string getName(){
        return icon;
    }

    // ...
}
```